# Binary string to Decimal integer converter

Tags: python, pseudocode

I am trying to write a program that converts a 4-bit string representation of binary into a decimal (base 10) integer.

This is what I got so far, but after I type In the 4-bit binary (e.g. 1101) It just comes out with: `'>>>'.`

Here is the flow diagram I am following: [image]

Here is my code:

```
def binaryToDenary():
    Answer = 0
    Column = 8
    Bit = int(input("Enter bit value: "))
    if Column >1:
        Answer = Answer + (Column * Bit)
        Column = Column/2
    elif Column <1:
        print("The decimal value is: " + Answer)


binaryToDenary()
```

What am I doing wrong? Any hints?

Comment: By denary, you mean base 10 right?

Comment: You know you can just use `int(binary, 2)` to go from base 2 to base 10.

Comment: You haven't implemented the loop.

Comment: @Malik The columns are to the base 2 I believe. Denary to the Base 10. Just normal integers.

Comment: whats wrong with `int('1101', 2)` . As an aside, you put so much effort into the diagram, but I believe you would be better served operating and thinking at the code level, instead of trying to model your algorithm as a diagram and "decompose" or "resolve" it into code.

Comment: @Preet the diagram is from an exam paper, I just print screened the picture. The exam question tells me to convert that flow diagram into code. Stupid AQA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't implemented the loop:

```
def binaryToDenary():
    Answer = 0
    Column = 8
    while not Column < 1:
        Bit = int(input("Enter bit value: "))
        Answer = Answer + (Column * Bit)
        Column = Column/2
    print("The decimal value is: {}".format(Answer))
```

Comment: You forgot that the answer is an integer, you need to interpolate into the string.

Comment: Are you serious you don know what string formatting is?

Comment: Ahh...interpolate the *int* into the string. Now I get it.

Comment: Could you please explain what this part of the code does: {}".format

Comment: Yeah, that's [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), which replaces sets of curly braces with its arguments. In this case, it inserts `Answer` after `"The decimal value is: "`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in methods or you can make your own function like so:

```
bintodec = lambda arg: sum(int(j) * 2**(len(arg) - i - 1) for i, j in enumerate(arg))
```

Comment: @Filip Use `bintodec('1010')` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is a direct translation from the diagram. Note that in production code and real libraries, this is not a particularly useful function and is only useful as an examination exercise.

```
def integer_from_binary_input():
    answer = 0
    column = 8
    while True:
        bit_chars = raw_input("Enter bit value:")
        assert len(bit_chars) == 1
        assert bit_chars in "01"
        bit = int(bit_chars)
        answer = answer + column * bit
        column /= 2
        if column < 1:
            break
    print "Decimal value is: %d" % answer
    return answer

output = integer_from_binary_input()
```