# Small python program - Binary string to Decimal integer converter stuck

Tags: python, while-loop, integer

Just making code which converts a 4 bit binary value to denary.
I have done this so far, but i keep getting syntax errors and its highlighting the >.

```
Answer = 0
Column = 8
while Column not < 1:
    Bit = int(input("Enter bit value: "))
    Answer = Answer + (Column * Bit)
    Column = Column/2
elif Column < 1:
    print("Decimal value is " + str(Answer))
```

Question similar to [Binary string to Decimal integer converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578704/binary-string-to-decimal-integer-converter/29578766#29578766) but that wasnt helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Is `not >` supposed to do the same thing as `<=`?

Comment: @wallyk made a small typo. it should be <

Comment: Have you to code something to do the conversion (for instance for school), or you can use an existing tool?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `not >` operator in Python. What you're trying to do is saying `<=`.

Anyway, it looks like you're doing something wrong here.
Maybe this helps:

```
while Column >= 1:
    try:
        Bit = int(input("Enter bit value: "))
        Answer = Answer + (Column * Bit)
        Column = Column/2
    except ValueError:
        print "wrong input"

    print("Decimal value is " + str(Answer))
```

The `elif` doesn't make sense both logically and syntacticly.

Comment: Why not catch what you are trying to catch?